# What do "single-step" and "multi-step" mean in post-hoc testing of ANOVAs?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons#Post-hoc_testing_of_ANOVAs)

> **Post-hoc testing of ANOVAs**
>
> Multiple comparison procedures are commonly used in an analysis of
>   variance after obtaining a significant omnibus test result, like the
>   ANOVA F-test. The significant ANOVA result suggests rejecting the
>   global null hypothesis H0 that the means are the same across the
>   groups being compared. Multiple comparison procedures are then used to
>   determine which means differ. In a one-way ANOVA involving K group
>   means, there are K(K − 1)/2 pairwise comparisons.
>
> A number of methods have been proposed for this problem, some of which
>   are:
>
> **Single-step procedures**
>
> - Tukey–Kramer method (Tukey's HSD) (1951)
> - Scheffe method (1953)
>
> **Multi-step procedures based on Studentized range statistic**
>
> - Duncan's new multiple range test (1955)
> - The Nemenyi test is similar to Tukey's range test in ANOVA.
> - The Bonferroni–Dunn test allows comparisons, controlling the familywise error rate.[vague]
> - Student Newman-Keuls post-hoc analysis
> - Dunnett's test (1955) for comparison of number of treatments to a single control group.

I was wondering what "single-step" and "multi-step" mean here?

Are they both for pairwise comparisons for every two groups, right?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single-step and step-wise relate to the view of the procedures as dynamic.

A single-step procedure implies there is no dynamics: without looking at the data, the procedure offers some rejection threshold.

A step-wise procedure implies there is dynamics: rejection boundaries are data driven and are updated along the sequence of p-values/test statistics in the data.

In reality, there is no real dynamics, as even the step-wise procedures take all test statistics, and returns a rejection boundary. The name stems mainly from the motivation to the procedure.

Comment: Thanks! (1) "updated along the sequence of p-values/test statistics in the data", does each in the "sequence" means for each individual test in the multiple comparison?  (2) A side question: are the above single-step and multi-step procedures all parametric, e.g. assuming the samples are normally distributed?

Comment: (1) each member of a "sequence" is a test statistic.
(2) you need to assume the marginal distribution of each test statistic.

Comment: Thanks, JohnRos! Since "In reality, there is no real dynamics, as even the step-wise procedures take all test statistics, and returns a rejection boundary", the rejection boundary must be specified completely before seeing the data, so how shall I understand "rejection boundaries are data driven and are updated along the sequence of p-values/test statistics in the data"?

Comment: I think I disagree with "the rejection boundary must be specified completely before seeing the data".

Comment: as a testing rule, isn't its rejection region completely specified before seeing any data? Do you mean the rejection region can change for different data? That will not be called testing.

Comment: Take the example of FDR. You choose your error rate and you choose the procedure (say, B-H). The rejection regions is not predetermined- it will be data driven.